# how to read lines with java.io.File

Tags: java, file-io

I got a txt file and I'm using `java.io.File` in my code. I want to read the txt of each line, each line can have more than one word.

```
23
10
23
C34
Crew Quarters
1
1
4
false
```

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: Have you tried reading one of results from https://www.google.com/search?q=java+read+lines+from+file?

Comment: Also a similar question: ["Best way to read a text file"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4716503/2991525)

Comment: this is how I use just with java.io.file cause Suppose that i can't add another reader, I know that exist other ways but it tells me that I have to use it with that io

Comment: *"Suppose that i can't add another reader, ..."* - Why can't you do that?  Is this a real problem or a hypothetical question (or a quiz)?

Answer (score 2):

Use loop then read all lines.

```
  for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/file.txt"))) {
        // ...
    }
```